# Selenium to test data downloaded to Excel Workbook from web page

Tags: excel, selenium, automation, apache-poi

can we test data that is be downloaded in to excel workbook (5-7 sheets in one workbook)? Here, after excuting selenium (Java Framework, Maven) code, an excel workbook wil be downloaded. Can we test that downloaded excel workbook for data, format and other details using selenium?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can but not exactly using selenium. You need to write separate java code to extract the data from the downloaded excel sheets and match it with the required parameters of your choice.